# How can I return String or JSONObject from asynchronous callback using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

For example, calling

```
api.getUserName(userId, new Callback<String>() {...});
```

cause:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: retrofit.converter.ConversionException:
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

I think I must disable gson parsing into POJOs but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: did you figure it out, I am getting the opposite error and trying to get an object back lol

Comment: @Lion789 No, I didn't yet :( I think that there is a way to return raw Response and then convert it to any object...

Comment: I actually figured it out, I was sending something that was not being accepted, so if you are sending results back make sure it is just a string or what you specify, let me know if that helps.

Comment: I meant that I want to convert response body to String... And the body isn't actually a string at all...

Comment: Well you will have to do that afterwards, you can't say the callback is going to be a string when it isn't in the callback convert it into a string

Comment: No problem but HOW? :) I can call [getBody()](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/client/Response.html#getBody()) but what to do with [TypedInput](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/mime/TypedInput.html) class?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I figured it out. It's embarrassing but it was very simple... **Temporary solution** may be like this:

```
 public void success(Response response, Response ignored) {
            TypedInput body = response.getBody();
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(body.in()));
                StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.append(line);
                    out.append(newLine);
                }

                // Prints the correct String representation of body. 
                System.out.println(out);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But if you want to get directly Callback the **Better way** is to use [Converter](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/converter/Converter.html).

```
public class Main {
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("/api/")
    public void getJson(Callback<String> callback);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setClient(new MockClient())
            .setConverter(new StringConverter())
            .setEndpoint("http://www.example.com").build();

    ApiService service = restAdapter.create(ApiService.class);
    service.getJson(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String str, Response ignored) {
            // Prints the correct String representation of body.
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            System.out.println("Failure, retrofitError" + retrofitError);
        }
    });
}

static class StringConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object fromBody(TypedInput typedInput, Type type) throws ConversionException {
        String text = null;
        try {
            text = fromStream(typedInput.in());
        } catch (IOException ignored) {/*NOP*/ }

        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public TypedOutput toBody(Object o) {
        return null;
    }

    public static String fromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
            out.append(newLine);
        }
        return out.toString();
    }
}

public static class MockClient implements Client {
    @Override
    public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
        URI uri = URI.create(request.getUrl());
        String responseString = "";

        if (uri.getPath().equals("/api/")) {
            responseString = "{result:\"ok\"}";
        } else {
            responseString = "{result:\"error\"}";
        }

        return new Response(request.getUrl(), 200, "nothing", Collections.EMPTY_LIST,
                new TypedByteArray("application/json", responseString.getBytes()));
    }
  }
}
```

If you know how to improve this code - please feel free to write about it.

Comment: This wouldn't work and would throw an error: **retrofit.RetrofitError:  No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)**

Comment: It had worked on publication time. If you are sure that there is a problem, let me know.

Comment: I am trying to build a custom converter for retrofit, but using the converter overrides my request too. I would like to have custom converter just for the response, how could I do that ? Thanks

Comment: That's a lot of boilerplate code.  Is this really the only way to parse Retrofit responses?

Comment: Great solution. And @r7v the solution to your problem (and mine, which is exactly what brought me to this page) would be to subclass `GsonConverter` and just override the `fromBody()` method, leaving the `toBody()` method intact.

Answer (score 32):

A possible solution would be to use `JsonElement` as the `Callback` type (`Callback<JsonElement>`). In your original example:

```
api.getUserName(userId, new Callback<JsonElement>() {...});
```

In the success method you can convert the `JsonElement` to either a `String` or a `JsonObject`.

```
JsonObject jsonObj = element.getAsJsonObject();
String strObj = element.toString();
```

Comment: This works but it's inefficient, as you have to convert the response to a JsonObject then back to a String. InputStream to String is much better, but a little trickier.

Answer (score 30):

> Retrofit 2.0.0-beta3 adds a `converter-scalars` module provides a
>   `Converter.Factory` for converting `String`, the 8 primitive types,
>   and the 8 boxed primitive types as `text/plain` bodies. Install this
>   before your normal converter to avoid passing these simple scalars
>   through, for example, a JSON converter.

So, first add `converter-scalars` module to `build.gradle` file for your application.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // use your Retrofit version (requires at minimum 2.0.0-beta3) instead of 2.0.0
    // also do not forget to add other Retrofit module you needed
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.0.0'
}
```

Then, create your `Retrofit` instance like this:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        // add the converter-scalars for coverting String
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(Service.class);
```

Now you can use API declaration like this:

```
interface Service {

    @GET("/users/{id}/name")
    Call<String> userName(@Path("userId") String userId);

    // RxJava version
    @GET("/users/{id}/name")
    Observable<String> userName(@Path("userId") String userId);
}
```

Comment: @lordmegamax this should be the accepted answer in 2017

Answer (score 21):

The answer may be much shorter than already mentioned and doesn't require any additional libraries:

In declaration use `Response` as follows:

```
... Callback<Response> callback);
```

And while handling response:

```
@Override
public void success(Response s, Response response) {
    new JSONObject(new String(((TypedByteArray) response.getBody()).getBytes()))
}
```

Comment: I used it when I was 1.9.4 but I don't know why it shouldn't work on 2.0

Comment: This is the correct answer if your POST doesn't return anything. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When @lordmegamax answer completely work there is much nicer solution which is come from

> Okio is a new library that complements java.io and java.nio

other squares project which already tight with `retrofit` and therefore you don't need to add any new dependency and it's have to be reliable:

```
ByteString.read(body.in(), (int) body.length()).utf8();
```

> ByteString is an immutable sequence of bytes. For character data, String is fundamental. ByteString is String's long-lost brother, making it easy to treat binary data as a value. This class is ergonomic: it knows how to encode and decode itself as hex, base64, and UTF-8.

Full example:

```
public class StringConverter implements Converter {
  @Override public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
    try {
      return ByteString.read(body.in(), (int) body.length()).utf8();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new ConversionException("Problem when convert string", e);
    }
  }

  @Override public TypedOutput toBody(Object object) {
    return new TypedString((String) object);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Implementing `Converter` is the key to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

To get Call JSONObject or JSONArray

you can create custom factory or copy it from here : https://github.com/marcinOz/Retrofit2JSONConverterFactory