# Retrofit callback get response body

Tags: android, retrofit

I am testing Retrofit to compare it with Volley and I am struggling to get the response from my requests. For example, I do something like this:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080")
            .build();

MyService service = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);
service.getToto("toto", new Callback<Toto>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Toto toto, Response response) {
            // Try to get response body
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
                String line;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String result = sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {}
    });
```

It works, the object `toto` is set, but for testing purposes, I also want to display the JSON response returned by the server.

So I am trying to read the `InputStream` from `response.getBody()` which is a `TypedInputStream`.
Unfortunately, I always get an `IOException : Stream is closed`.

I tried to use the [Utils](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/Utils.java) class from Retrofit but I get the same `IOException` error.

Comment: I think that you can use custom Converter to delegate parsing to real converter and log server's response [More info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22820153/1308475)

Comment: im having the same issue. similarly simple setup, my actual custom response object is fine, populated and whatnot, but when i try and grab the inputstream from the response directly, same error. but response inputstream in `failure()` works fine

Comment: actually just noticed something weird. when i turned on logging in retrofit, and it spits out all the info i want to see anyway, my inputstream consuming works fine, no error thrown. weirdd...

Comment: @trippedout see my answer below...

Comment: you can use `JsonObject` as response, then get your `String` from `josnObject.toString()`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Inside callback's angle brackets write "Response" and then extract the stream from this response.

```
service.getToto("toto", new Callback<Response>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Response result, Response response) {

        //Try to get response body
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));

            String line;

            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String result = sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @Kerwan If this answer helped you, kindly select this answer and up vote it so that it can help others as well

Comment: Yes thank you ! I forgot about my question, I used Volley instead but your solution works :)

Comment: If I follow your approach, I get an error: **retrofit.RetrofitError: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Try my other answer. May be that will help you. Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853552/retrofit-sending-post-request-to-server-in-android/24550953?noredirect=1#comment48091580_24550953

Comment: @NiteshKhatri My main problem was specifying a data type and a callback in an RXJava observable.  Retrofit only returns one callback as far as RXJava is concerned (observable).  So I just introspect the Retrofit Response now as the sole return type, and the problem goes away.

Comment: When you say add a "Response" object in the Callback's angle bracket, that requires changing the @POST request parameters. Do you use the Response from com.squareup.okhttp or Retrofit.client? I am having an issue which I posted in the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068601/how-to-handle-jsonsyntaxexception-when-receiving-response-from-gae

Comment: I have been looking for the answer for ages, somehow I i haven't found it. thanks. it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 29):

**Before Retrofit 2.0**

```
   String bodyString = new String(((TypedByteArray) response.getBody()).getBytes());
```

**Retrofit 2.0**

```
 String  bodyString = new String(response.body().bytes());
```

Comment: This solution is great because I can have my response type and eat it.

Comment: @shiami Cannot resolve symbol 'TypedByteArray'. Where can I get this class?

Comment: @anivaler I think it's not working anymore for Retrofit 2.0+

Comment: bodyString = new String(response.body().bytes()); for Retrofit 2.0

Comment: @Robert i am getting " Cannot resolve method 'bytes()' " when I try this ^ line of code.

Comment: Great Answer ! ,Finally i got solution after 20 hr , Thank You so much sir :) .

Answer (score 23):

If you set `.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)` on the `RestAdapter` that you use to create the service you should get the raw JSON response output in the debug console.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setServer("http://my_lovely_api.com")
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
    .build();

mService = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);
```

If you want to do something different with this raw response you can still use the code you have in your success block to create a JSON string assuming that you keep the `LogLevel.FULL` in the `setLogLevel` method, if not then it won't parse the InputStream from `response.getBody().in()` as it's already been read and closed.

Comment: Great!   .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) helps me

Comment: this is useful only when your app is running in DEBUG. it is a good solution especially since we dont want to log in release builds. I unfortunately had to write logs in a release build. So, this solution doesnt work in such cases. I am using retrofit 1.9

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered a similar problem. I wanted to look at some json in the response body but didn't want to deal with the TypedByteArray from Retrofit. I found the quickest way to get around it was to make a Pojo(Plain Old Java Object) with a single String field. More Generally you would make a Pojo with one field corresponding to whatever data you wanted to look at.

For example, say I was making a request in which the response from the server was a single string in the response's body called "access_token"

My Pojo would look like this:

```
public class AccessToken{
    String accessToken;

    public AccessToken() {}

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

and then my callback would look like this

```
Callback<AccessToken> callback = new Callback<AccessToken>() {
   @Override
   public void success(AccessToken accessToken, Response response) {
       Log.d(TAG,"access token: "+ accessToken.getAccessToken());
   }

   @Override
   public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
       Log.E(TAG,"error: "+ error.toString());
   }
};
```

This will enable you to look at what you received in the response.

Answer (score 3):

Please, don't use streams and straemReaders for this.
Use smart solutions like square does:

```
private Response logAndReplaceResponse(String url, Response response, long elapsedTime)
```

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=retrofit-jaxrs-master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java

example:

```
private String getResponseBody(Response response) {
    String result = "";
    //Try to get response body
    if (response.getBody() instanceof TypedByteArray) {
        TypedByteArray b = (TypedByteArray) response.getBody();
        result = new String(b.getBytes());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to do something like the following:

```
  private static String bodyAsString(RequestBody body) {
    try {
      Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
      body.writeTo(buffer);
      return buffer.readString(body.contentType().charset());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Taken from https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okcurl/src/test/java/com/squareup/okhttp/curl/MainTest.java#L93-L101

Answer (score 1):

With version 2.1.0, you can get the content as

```
public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
    String errorString = response.errorBody().string();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
ModelClass modelclass=response.response.body()
System.out.println("****************-----retro rsp----1-------"+modelclass.getMessage());
```

Answer (score -1):

in your model of response press cmd+n and override "toString" method and only call as response.toString();

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "{" +
            "key_one='" + var_keyone + '\'' +
            ", key_two='" + var_keytwo + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```