# Intercept and add POST paramaters

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using retrofit on Android application to intercept and add some ID infos on all my queries.

Here is how it works with GET request :

```
RequestInterceptor identityParameters = new RequestInterceptor()
    {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addQueryParam("uuid", uuid);
                request.addQueryParam("key", key);
        }
    };
```

This works well with GET request and I get my request like : /request?uuid=123&key=123

But for POST request it adds it exactly the same way (as GET parameters, in the URL)... How Can i have different behaviour for each annotation and how can i add POST type parameters to the query ?

Comment: This will help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853552/retrofit-sending-post-request-to-server-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853552/retrofit-sending-post-request-to-server-in-android

Comment: This will help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853552/retrofit-sending-post-request-to-server-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853552/retrofit-sending-post-request-to-server-in-android

Comment: thank you for your comments. Unfortunately this is not what i am looking for. my POST request works well by itself, but I don't know how to intercept it with RequestInterceptor to add POST parameters.

Answer (score 0):

find here [RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RequestInterceptor.RequestFacade.html) class
it only have methods to add `PathParams`, `QueryParam` and `Headers`
so POST looks not allowed, i think you can't do that.