# Retrofit. Android. Can I download json object to String without parsing?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Can I download json object as a String without parsing with Retrofit on Android device?

When I tried direct approach

```
@GET("/api.php?action=bundle")
public void getWholeScheduleString(Callback<String> response);
```

I got error:

```
"com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"
```

Comment: see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31898210/retrofit-jsonobject-jsonobject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the response is a JSON Object and not a String. You could do the following:
First change the getter method:

```
@GET("/api.php?action=bundle")
public void getWholeScheduleString(Callback<JsonObject> response);
```

Then in the `success(JsonObject json, Response res)` method of your Callback you just map it to a String:

```
@Override
public void success(JsonObject response, Response arg1) {
    String myResponse = response.getAsString();
}
```

EDIT: By the way, you can parameterize the query part (?action=bundle) to make the method more generic like this:

```
@GET("/api.php")
public void getWhateverAction(@Query("action") String action, Callback<JsonObject> response);
```

You pass the 'action' as a String argument whenever you call the method.

Comment: Callback<JsonObject> response where <JsonObject> is an object of google gson library. it is not from org.json.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Callback<String> response`, you can use `Callback<Response> response`, so your code will look like that:

```
@GET("/api.php?action=bundle")
public void getWholeScheduleString(Callback<Response> response);
```

Afterwards, you can access body of the response in the following way:

```
response.getBody().toString();
```

I am not sure if it will work correctly, but you can try that.

Comment: TypedByteArray[length=5791066] is not exactly what I wanted, but I guess I'am close.

Comment: Actually, the `Response` contains a stream still to be read. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325641/retrofit-callback-get-response-body).

Comment: Niek is right. `Response.getBody()` returns stream instead of String. I found thread describing how to convert `TypedInput` to `String`. Check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22820153/1150795 . `TypedInput` will be returned in `response.getBody()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GSON to get the response object back to JSON string by adding this inside the `success(SomeType JSON_Response_Object, Response res)` method of Retrofit callback

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(JSON_Response_Object);
```