# Can't get json response with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, post, retrofit

I'm using retrofit 1.9.0 and I had tried the following code to get a response in json format:

```
public void Execute(String email, String password, Callback<User> callback) {
    final Callback<User> cb = callback;
    RestAdapter restAdapter = buildRestAdapter();
    System.out.println("Email " + email + " passowrd " + password);
    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword(password);
    restAdapter.create(YutonAPI.class).postLogin(
            user,
            new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void success(User user, Response response) {
                    System.out.println("succes");
                    System.out.println(response.getBody());
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    System.out.println("error "+ error);
                }
            });
}
```

So this line of code:

```
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

Should give me a response in json format however it didn't work because I'm getting the following output:

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA642.png

So this is how my response in json format should look like:

```
{
    "user": {
        "image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e0a190604dc3dd2ee7b66bb95c20ef7f?d=identicon&s=512"
        "email": "a@hotmail.com"
        "name": "a"
        "id": "566dfac21043a31820bf1ae6"
    } -
}
```

I had already tested it on my server where I was making a post request. Below you can see a screenshot of it:

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJPbA.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `response.getBody()` returns a `TypedInputStream` object, which you can't directly output because it isn't a `String`.

To read a `TypedInputStream` there are several options, as posted in: [Retrofit callback get response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325641/retrofit-callback-get-response-body), the easiest being:

```
String body = new String(((TypedByteArray) response.getBody()).getBytes());
```

If the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient$TypedInputStream cannot be cast to retrofit.mime.TypedByteArray
```

Then make sure that you set [`.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325641/retrofit-callback-get-response-body/25767010#25767010) on the `RestAdapter` that you use to create the service.