# Trying to read 2D array from Json to Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a problem reading my Json document because I want to read a 2d array looking like this:

> "map" :           [
>                 ["PARED", "PARED", "PARED", "PARED", "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "SNOWMAN" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "PUERTA"],
>                 ["PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "SOL" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "SOL" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "SOL" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "SOL" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "SOL" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "SOL" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED" , "ESPACIO" , "PARED"],
>                 ["PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED" , "PARED"]             ]

And convert it to a "String [][] mapa;" array in Android Studio, but I don't know how to read and cast it.

I really apreciate your help.

EDIT: I tried something like this, but I don't know how to continue:

> mapObject.getJSONArray("map")

EDIT2 something like that?:

> JSONArray mapatest = mapObject.getJSONArray("map");
>
> ```
>             String[][] innerArray = null;
>
>             for(int t = 0; t < mapatest.getCount(); t++){
>
>                 innerArray[t] = mapatest.getJSONArray(t);
>
>                 for(int k = 0; k < innerArray.getCount(); t++){
>
>                     innerArray[t][k] = mapatest.getString(k);
>
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: Souloibur, what client do you use to get this json?

Comment: see my answer, this way is simple and quick - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720204/retrofit-returns-linkedtreemap-instead-of-json/33720542#33720542

Comment: I am downloading it from my server.

Comment: try to get it with Retrofit (see link above) and you will not parse array

Comment: I don't know how to use that, I am starting with this.

Answer (score 1):

While mapObejct.getJSONArray("map") returns an array where each entry is the X of your table, each item of the array will be an Array itself (getJSONArray again) and will be your Y of the table.

The code would looks like:

```
map = obj.getJSONArray("map);
for(int i = 0; i < map.getCount(); i++){
   innerArray = map.getJSONArray(i);
   for(int k = 0; k < innerArray.getCount(); i++){
      innerItem = map.getString(k);
   }      
}
```

This will navigate trought i,k where they would be your array[i][k]

EDIT: With your code:

```
 JSONArray mapatest = mapObject.getJSONArray("map");
        String[][] innerArray = null;

        for(int t = 0; t < mapatest.getCount(); t++){
            JSONArray innerArrayObj = mapatest.getJSONArray(t);
            innerArray[t] = new String[innerArrayObj.getCount());

            for(int k = 0; k < innerArrayObj.getCount(); t++){

                innerArray[t][k] = innerArrayObj.getString(k);

            }
        }
```

Comment: I think I am not understanding it, I have this but it doesn't work. Thank you for your help.

(I can't post code here, so I'll put it in the question.)

Comment: Oh.. one miss, check the answer

Comment: Yes it seems it will work, but I have an error in getCount(). "Cannot resolve method"

Comment: I've changed "getCount()" to "length()" but now I have this error:

E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array

In this line: innerArray[t] = new String[innerArrayObj.length()];

Comment: You must add innerArray = new String[mapatest.getCount()][]; before the for