# TwitterApiClient: what is Callback signature for POST?

Tags: android, twitter, callback, http-post, retrofit

What is the proper way to specify a Callback when doing a POST for "/1.1/lists/create.json"?

Here is the Twitter API doc: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/lists/create

***MyTwitterApiClient***

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiClient;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User;

import retrofit.http.Field;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.http.Query;

class MyTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {
    public MyTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) {
        super(session);
    }

    public CustomService getCustomService() {
        return getService(CustomService.class);
    }
}

interface CustomService {
    @GET("/1.1/users/show.json")
    void show(@Query("user_id") long id, Callback<User> cb);

    @POST("/1.1/lists/create.json")
    // I was incorrectly using @Field instead of @Query, be careful!
    void createList(@Query("name") String name, @Query("mode") String mode, Callback cb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way to solve this issue, but it works for me.  Credit goes to @tposchel via [How can I return String or JSONObject from asynchronous callback using Retrofit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881943/how-can-i-return-string-or-jsonobject-from-asynchronous-callback-using-retrofit).

**MyTwitterApiClient.java** changed Callback type to JsonElement

```
interface CustomService {
    @GET("/1.1/users/show.json")
    void show(@Query("user_id") long id, Callback<User> cb);

    @POST("/1.1/lists/create.json")
    void createList(@Query("name") String name, @Query("mode") String mode, Callback<JsonElement> cb);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
MyTwitterApiClient api = new MyTwitterApiClient(session);
api.getCustomService().createList("MyListName", "private", new Callback<JsonElement>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<JsonElement> result) {
       Log.d(TAG, " [success] status: " + result.response.getStatus());
       JsonElement je = result.data;
       Log.d(TAG, " [success] data: " + je.getAsJsonObject().toString());
    }
    @Override
       public void failure(TwitterException e) { }
    });
```